# How to represent $Prob(X_1+X_2 \leq a, X_2+X_3 \leq b, X_3 +X_4 > c)$ with mutually independent random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

There are four mutually independent random variables: 
$$X_i : \Omega \to \mathbb R$$
for $i= 1,2,3,4$

The cumulative distribution function of them is given as $F_i(x_i)$.

How to represent $Prob(X_1+X_2 \leq a, X_2+X_3 \leq b, X_3 +X_4 > c)$ in terms of $F_i$?

Comment: Interesting problem. Have you any thoughts so far?

Comment: @KimJongUn I'm trying to link this problem with the well-known problem $Prob(\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}\cap[1,n]}X_i \leq a)$, which can be solved by induction, if I know how to represent, the most basic one, $Prob(X_1+X_2 \leq a)$. But induction is not applicable to the situation here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First,
$$P(X_1+X_2 \leq a, X_2+X_3 \leq b, X_3 +X_4 > c)=E[P(X_1+X_2 \leq a, X_2+X_3 \leq b, X_3 +X_4 > c|X_2,X_3)].$$
As far as the conditional probability:
$$P(X_1+X_2 \leq a, X_2+X_3 \leq b, X_3 +X_4 > c|X_2=x_2,X_3=x_3)=$$
$$=P(X_1 \leq a-x_2, x_2+x_3 \leq b,  X_4 > c-x_3|X_2=x_2,X_3=x_3)=$$
$$
=\begin{cases}
0, & \text{ if } & x_2+x_3>b\\
F_1(a-x_2)(1-F_4(c-x_3)),& \text{ otherwise. }
\end{cases}
$$
Finally,
$$P(X_1+X_2 \leq a, X_2+X_3 \leq b, X_3 +X_4 > c)=$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F_1(a-x_2)\left(\int_{-\infty}^{-x_2+b}(1-F_4(c-x_3))dF_3\right)dF_2.$$